# Adding a new theme in moodle

Tags: moodle

I have downloaded a theme for moodle and i tried to add  it to the existing themes using method B in the following link(using plugin).
    https://www.vidyamantra.com/sales/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/242/0/how-to-install-new-theme-in-moodle

```
as per the steps the theme got updated in the plugin list but it is not visible in the themes(no change in available theme) so that i could not change my moodle theme.

so,please help me to resole this..
```

Comment: It might be because the theme you downloaded isn't compatible with the version of Moodle. What version of Moodle are you using? And what is the download link for the theme?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. Certain servers (depending on how they're configured and what version of PHP is installed) will not parse the theme's PHP files correctly.

If you find that you're uploading themes via the front-end and they're not coming up, you will need to upload via FTP/cPanel (Method A).

Comment: Hi Preethi. If you've tried method A and it didn't work, it's most likely a problem with the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using FTP, I use WinSCP (windows) then locate the "theme" folder.

"/var/www/html/yourMoodle/theme"

upload "yourTheme.zip" to this folder.

the using ssh unzip the file. (ubuntu)

```
usr$ sudo unzip /var/www/html/yourMoodle/theme/yourTheme.zip && sudo rm yourTheme.zip
```

then go to your moodle and change the theme

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the downloaded theme and put it under theme/ directory. Run the upgrade from cli

```
cd admin/cli/
php upgrade.php
```

You should see it under theme when you login as administrator.